# Python : How to read through columns in text files?

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, text-processing

I have a text file with delimited by space, which looks like below

```
title 1 589.890 0.260 Fine 0.100 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 590.150 0.000 . 0.950 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 592.290 0.130 Here 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 592.420 0.160 I 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 592.580 0.280 go 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 592.860 0.000 , 0.100 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 593.180 0.270 taking 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 593.450 0.170 Russel 0.990 lex larry_page person_name russel_arnold object
title 1 593.640 0.060 for 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 593.700 0.110 the 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 593.810 0.460 team 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 594.270 0.000 . 0.950 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 594.920 0.140 In 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 595.060 0.090 the 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 595.150 0.360 sack 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 595.510 0.000 . 0.950 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 598.810 0.360 Hey 0.100 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 599.170 0.460 Helen 0.990 lex larry_page person_name helen_winkle addressee
title 1 599.630 0.000 . 0.950 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 600.490 0.170 Hi 0.530 lex helen_winkle " " "
title 1 600.740 0.290 guys 0.530 lex helen_winkle " " "
title 1 601.030 0.000 . 0.950 lex helen_winkle " " "
title 1 602.010 0.220 Helen 0.990 lex larry_page person_name helen_winkle addressee
title 1 602.230 0.000 , 0.100 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 602.280 0.140 I 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 602.470 0.100 have 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 602.600 0.030 a 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 602.950 0.350 question 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 603.300 0.180 for 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 603.480 0.190 you 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 603.670 0.000 , 0.100 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 603.670 0.060 and 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 603.730 0.070 it 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 603.840 0.180 might 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 604.020 0.200 be 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 604.220 0.460 a 0.100 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 604.680 0.170 little 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 604.850 0.550 awkward 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 605.400 0.000 , 0.100 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 605.610 0.090 you 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 605.700 0.320 know 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 606.020 0.000 , 0.100 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 606.340 0.260 given 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 606.660 0.130 that 0.990 lex larry_page " " "
title 1 606.870 0.330 I 0.990 lex larry_page " "
```

Here I'm trying to reformat on the basis of column[7]

```
start_time end_time column[7] column[9]names
```

I'm trying reformat the text like this :

```
589.890 599.630 larry_page russel_arnold helen_winkle   
600.490 601.030 helen_winkle "
602.010 607,200 larry_page helen_winkle
```

In the above format helen_winkle has no names in column[9] so I gave "

Ps : Sometimes, It may have more names like below

```
589.890 599.630 larry_page russel_arnold helen_winkle jerome_halloy leo_cazenille
```

I just stuck here and don't have any idea for how to proceed further

```
path = "path of the textfile"
with open(path,'r') as f :
        for line in f:
            columns = line.strip().split()
            start = float(columns[2])
            end = start+float(columns[3])
            pro_name = columns[9]
            s_name = columns[7]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is part of a more general problem called "corner turning" - rows in, columns out. It's a difficult problem to do efficiently, though the data is mostly numerical when you read about it in academic papers.

In this case, what I'd do is create empty lists, then append values to them during the for-loop.

```
path = "path of the textfile"
start_list = []
end_list = []
pro_name_list = []
s_name_list = []
with open(path,'r') as f :
    for line in f:
        columns = line.strip().split()
        start = float(columns[2])
        start_list.append(start)
        end = start+float(columns[3])
        end_list.append(end)
        pro_name = columns[9]
        pro_name_list.append(pro_name)
        s_name = columns[7]
        s_name_list.append(s_name)
```

Edit: just re-read your question and realised I hadn't really answered it properly... But I think once you have arrays representing the columns, you can re-create the file with whatever order you need to? Did I understand what you asked correctly?

Comment: Your'e Idea is good. By the way  I'm finding it  difficult to do the "for loop" to match  s_name_list and start time and end time.

Comment: Again, you're going to have to clarify there. I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: How do I exactly reformat like this  "589.890 599.630 larry_page russel_arnold helen_winkle"

Comment: @Rangooski: If you've got lists with your fields in them, just use write strings to the file or the screen:
`file.write("{:s} {:s} {:s}".format(start_list[i], end_list[i], name_list[i])`
Obviously you'd need to do that inside a `for` loop.

Comment: @Rangooski - if this answers your question, please mark it!